# Experience Profile not displaying anything

Tags: experience-profile

When I load up the experience profile this is what I see:

[image]

This is the error immediately when I load the experience profile page. Tried to find other solutions online but found none:

```
2021-09-29 11:57:02.443 +08:00 [Error] Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.XdbSearchOperation`1[Sitecore.XConnect.Contact]: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrResults.JsonResultsParser.ParseSearchResponse[TSolrResult](JsonTextReader reader)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrResults.JsonResultsParser.<ParseSearchResponseWithCursorMark>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrReader.<ExecuteQuery>d__14`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrReader.<GetSearchResults>d__13`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrReader.<SearchContacts>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Repository.<SearchContacts>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.RepositoryCountersDecorator.<SearchContacts>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Service.RepositorySearchInvoker.<Execute>d__7.MoveNext()
2021-09-29 11:57:02.455 +08:00 [Error] ["XdbContextLoggingPlugin"] XdbContext Batch Execution Exception
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrResults.JsonResultsParser.ParseSearchResponse[TSolrResult](JsonTextReader reader)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrResults.JsonResultsParser.<ParseSearchResponseWithCursorMark>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrReader.<ExecuteQuery>d__14`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrReader.<GetSearchResults>d__13`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrReader.<SearchContacts>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Repository.<SearchContacts>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.RepositoryCountersDecorator.<SearchContacts>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Service.RepositorySearchInvoker.<Execute>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you on?

Comment: @MarkCassidy sitecore 9

Comment: Could you please add some more insights here, such as is it an upgraded environment, how you set up the environment and databases, is there any customization and how solr setup is done etc?

Comment: Experience profile depends upon Search indexes. Can you please check that records are coming at Solr core side? Are you seeing any issue in experience Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

From the information in your error message, it sounds like you might have a corrupted contact email or name or one that has a special character that the json does not expect.

Depending on how large your list of contacts is, you could review them manually or perhaps export them from list manager. Then perhaps throw the list into a csv to json converter and see if you can find the troublemaker.